# Should I put all components state in the Store?

Tags: redux

Assuming I have a SearchBar component with some inputs, should I put SearchBar's input state in the Store? If not, what kind of state should I put in the Store, and what does not belong in the store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You certainly want to keep track of the input state. Whether it's in the component state or in the store is up to you. My practice is to make all my components "dumb" and hold all the state in the store. Here's why:

With something like a search bar, it's easy to imagine you'd want to display that information elsewhere. For example, say the user searched for "kittens". You might have a separate component in the page that says:

```
Showing results 1 to 10 for "kittens"
```

Thus you wouldn't want your search query state tucked away in your search bar component where other components can't get at it.